# Cmake error while configuring all projects in VS Code [Pi Pico]

Tags: c, cmake, compilation, raspberry-pi-pico

I just bought a pico and I want to make a simple audio player. I followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwPTpMuvSXg&ab_channel=RobinGrosset) and have the circuit ready, I needed to flash my pico so I followed [another tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55iPBJgxN4U&ab_channel=CircuitSecrets). I did everything just like in the tutorial and I have the examples ready. The next thing I did was configuring all projects and I encountered this error:

```
The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" -Sc:/pico/pico-examples -Bc:/pico/pico-examples/build -G Ninja exited with code: 1 and signal: null
```

I rechecked the tutorial and searched for this error but found nothing. I hoped this would be a plug-and-play experience after the setup but unfortunately, that's not the case. I'm a beginner and so I don't know much about microcontrollers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74552501/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others.
In this case there is probably some error in `CMakeLists.txt`. Please provide it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

update here. The next day I uninstalled everything and redid the tutorial. It turns out that I missed the checkbox for `experimental support` and changed the default editor to `Notepad++`. At that point I continued with the tutorial and the only other issue I encountered was the fact that compiling with `NMake Makerfiles` didn't work - so I just used `Ninja` instead. All is well now and I hope that I helped someone with this post that has the same issues as I have.